# using two arrays in a for each loop

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I have this code that inserts data into two different arrays using vb.net:

```
salesman_product(salesman_product_counter) = reader2.GetString(0)
salesman_product_amount(salesman_product_counter) = "£" + Val(reader2.GetString(1)).ToString("F2")
```

`salesman_product_counter` is a number that has +1 each time (the arrays are inside a while loop)

creating the array is working fine, how can i loop through both arrays to get the data?

I have tried:

```
For Each salesman_product2 In salesman_product and salesman_product_amount2 in salesman_product_amount
Salesman_xlWorkSheet.Cells(salesman_product2, 1) = company_name 'client name
Salesman_xlWorkSheet.Cells(salesman_product2, 2) = customer_account 'client account
Salesman_xlWorkSheet.Cells(salesman_product2, 3) = salesman_product2 'product
Salesman_xlWorkSheet.Cells(salesman_product2, 4) = reader4.GetString(0) 'commission percentage
Salesman_xlWorkSheet.Cells(salesman_product2, 5) = Lines_International_Calls * (reader4.GetString(0) / 100) 'commission amount
Next
```

but you cannot use AND

i need to be able to see data from both arrays inside a loop

Comment: Use For indx = 0 to salesman_Product.GetUpperBound(0) instead of For Each?

Comment: if only there was a way to keep related information like `salesman`, `product` and [all together in one thing...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973814.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to loop the index.

```
For index As Integer = 0 To salesman_product.Count-1
    salesman_product2 = salesman_product(index)
    salesman_product_amount2 = salesman_product_amount(index)
    Salesman_xlWorkSheet.Cells(salesman_product2, 1) = company_name 'client name
    Salesman_xlWorkSheet.Cells(salesman_product2, 2) = customer_account 'client account
    Salesman_xlWorkSheet.Cells(salesman_product2, 3) = salesman_product2 'product
    Salesman_xlWorkSheet.Cells(salesman_product2, 4) = reader4.GetString(0) 'commission percentage
    Salesman_xlWorkSheet.Cells(salesman_product2, 5) = Lines_International_Calls * (reader4.GetString(0) / 100) 'commission amount
Next
```

But the right way to do this is not to create 2 array, but to have a list of a class

You'll need to create a class for the salesman information

```
Class SalesmanProduct
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Amount As String
End Class
```

Add the products to a list

```
Dim salesmanProducts As New List(Of SalesmanProduct)

' ...

Dim newProduct As New SalesmanProduct

newProduct.Name = reader2.GetString(0)
newProduct.Amount = "£" + Val(reader2.GetString(1))

salesmanProducts.Add(newProduct)
```

And then you can "For Each" the list

```
For Each product As SalesmanProduct In salesmanProducts
    ' product.Name
    ' product.Amount
Next
```

I could argue that storing the amount as a string in the database is a bad idea, but that's unrelated to this question.